# nginclude add / to the main url

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-include

Any idea why this is happening?

I try to use

```
ng-include="'html_template'"
```

URL Result **WITH** ng-include

```
http://localhost/app/grid#/leave
```

URL Result **WITHOUT** ng-include

```
http://localhost/app/grid#leave
```

Notice that the forward slash "/" is added.

Comment: Anyone has any idea?

Comment: This is a mystery. no one knows why?

Comment: Could you maybe provide a JSFiddle, not enough context to solve this.

Comment: Are you saying that using ng-include causes your page to be redirect from `http://localhost/app/grid#leave` to `http://localhost/app/grid#/leave`? It is unclear.

Comment: @pasine, using ng-include added '/' to the url instead of http://localhost/app/grid#leave it becomes http://localhost/app/grid#/leave

Comment: @in_visible can you share some code? The route configuration, the included template and the controller, or anything useful.

Comment: My first guesses would be: 1) the app cannot find the template file and redirect the user to another route, or 2) the included template has a controller that redirect the user for some reason. Share some code and we will sort it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is question and answer about that

[Preserve traditional anchor behavior with ng-include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299966/preserve-traditional-anchor-behavior-with-ng-include)

In summary of that answer, ng-include requires $anchorScroll, and $anchorScroll requires $location. As long as $location is involved, it changes the normal hash to angular hasn

This is my answer to the same problem you have, https://stackoverflow.com/a/27529032/454252

Basically Angular changes the URL with ng-include because $location service is involved, and the way get around is little tricky

Comment: This is a hacky way. I have already done similar thing by replacing the hash. looking for more elegant solution.

Comment: @in_visible, if you want an elegant solution, 1) you should have asked the solution for this problem.  2) you should have listed what you have tried to solve problem. Without asking it and listing what you already knew(you might be an expert in Angular), there is no way that I know what you want.